# iMessage "not delivered" - but it does deliver?

Tags: text-messaging

Suddenly all messages I write in iMessage on my iMac are marked as "not delivered" (the messages are green), but the messages are sent. So Why are they sent, yet marked with an error?

I'm in the same WLAN with my iPhone. Everything is activated on both devices. The messages I write on the iMac don't appear on the iPhone.

Comment: Sign out, sign back in - usually fixes weirdness

Comment: I've signet out on my mac and iphone. That doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

on the iPhone under `Settings > Messages > SMS Forwarding` one have to activate the computer which promts a code who is displayed on the computer.

It seems as if in the last os uptade this was disabled.

What a great update feature.